# How to write an sh script?

Tags: unix, sh

I hope I'm using the correct terminology here, but I want to write a script to execute in unix, that will execute a number of commands sequentially (i.e. one after another). Could I just put the commands that I want in notepad, separate them with an newline character, and then save it as script.sh and then do

```
sh script.sh
```

Comment: Is Google Down? I could find an abundance of answers to the question when I entered it into the searchbox...

Comment: Your statement is correct however it's not really a question.

Comment: By "notepad", do you mean the Windows text editor? Are you using Cygwin? If so, watch out for line endings; sh and bash on Cygwin commonly choke on Windows-style line endings. `man dos2unix` for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a [shebang/hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the top

`#!/bin/sh`

Comment: If you want to execute the script directly, it should start with `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`; then you can just run `./script` rather than `sh ./script`. Without the shebang, it will probably be executed by `/bin/sh`, but the shebang is a good idea unless you always intend to run the shell explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make sure the execute bit is set for your script file.  Also, you could specify which application to use to run your script.  By default, if you don't specify an application, it will default to using the current shell that's executing your script.  I usually put the application specifically such as the following...

```
#!/bin/bash
```

That will specify that `bash` should be used to process your script.  If you get into any special scripting, you will want to be specific since there are differences between `sh`, `bash`, `ksh`, etc.

Also, since you mentioned you wanted to run several commands in sequence, you might want to use some conditions.

One easy condition would be to use either `&&` or `||` in your script.  This will allow you to specify what happens when the command executes successfully or not.  For example...

```
#!/bin/bash

command1 || exit
command2 || exit
command3
```

This would try to execute command1 **or** exit if not successful (return code higher than 0).  Otherwise it would continue to execute the following lines.

Another example which uses the `&&` syntax which means "**and**"...

```
command1 && command2 && command3
```

Finally, you may want to check the return codes specifically and respond with error messages.

```
#!/bin/bash

command1
if [ $? -gt 0 ] ; then
  echo "command1 failed with error code $?"
  exit
fi
command2 ....
```

That last example is more advanced shell scripting but something you may want to pursue further.  If you get into any conditional scripting, always remember to add your shebang (#!/bin/bash) for the proper shell.

Answer (score 0):

I've only tested this in bash, but you can just put each command on its own line, no shebang or anything necessary.  You'll have to give the file execute permissions with chmod, then you can run it with

```
    ./myscript
```

(assuming that "myscript" is in the current directory).